# x-text is not working on <H4> tag in Alpine JS. Why?

Tags: alpine.js

I just want to know is there an issue with my code or just some alpine js functionality. Here is my code

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column ml-4" x-data={ data(); }>
    <span class="d-flex flex-column">
        <h4 class="font-weight-bold" x-text="price"></h4>
    </span>
</div>
```

and my JS code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function data()
    {
        return {
            price: 50
        }
    }

</script>
```

The output doesn't print anything. But, if I change the line from

```
<h4 class="font-weight-bold" x-text="price"></h4>
```

to

```
<p class="font-weight-bold" x-text="price"></p>
```

then it works fine and I got the text `50` as output. Why is this happening? Is there anything wrong that I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your `x-data` should be `x-data="data()"` so that `{ price: 50 }` is the Alpine state.

See the following pen with that change https://codepen.io/hugodf/pen/BaLERbe.